# "Non è loro chiara", "non è chiara a loro" oppure ambedue?

Tags: phrase-choice

Qualche giorno fa, volevo esprimere che una cosa non era chiara a parecchie persone e ho avuto il dubbio su quale espressione usare:

> non è loro chiara

oppure

> non è chiara a loro.

Posso usare tutte e due o una di queste forme è preferibile all'altra?

Non mi riferisco unicamente alla correttezza grammaticale, ma anche al fatto che suoni naturale in italiano moderno.

Comment: Entrambe forme sono corrette, direi che la prima suona più “formale” mentre la seconda è più colloquiale e quindi più usata.

Comment: Ricordo che, anche se fa storcere il naso ai puristi, non muore nessuno se si dice “non gli è chiara”, che in un registro non formale suona più naturale di tutte. Infatti il pronome “gli” è usato spesso anche come “forma atona del dativo plurale maschile e femminile, col sign. di «a loro»: _Chi si cura di costoro a Milano? Chi gli darebbe retta?_ (Manzoni); _le belle ragazze di qui non sono degne di portargli le scarpe, a quelle di Napoli_ (Verga)” ([Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gli2)).

Comment: Il lieve problema di “non è chiara a loro” è che pone un po' troppo l'accento su “a loro”, quasi a sottintendere che ad altri invece la cosa è chiara.

Comment: Concordo con @DaG, l'uso del loro come complemento di termine suona un po' affettato nel parlato: se la domanda è "quale suona più naturale", decisamente "non gli è chiara".

Comment: @DaG Non muore nessuno ma " 'na bella lacrimuccia alla maestra di italiano _gliela_ tiri giù"! `:-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delle forme proposte:

> (La cosa) non è loro chiara

è corretta ma tende a suonare formale, soprattutto se detta a voce, mentre

> ...non è chiara a loro

oltre a mantenere ancora una certa formalità, pone un po' troppo l'accento su “a loro”, quasi a sottintendere che ad altri invece la cosa è chiara.

Alle forme proposte aggiungo

> ...non gli è chiara

che fa storcere il naso ai puristi non-linguisti e alle maestre di scuola non aggiornate, ma che in un registro non formale suona più naturale di tutte, e non faceva storcere il naso a Galilei né a Manzoni, a Verga né a Pavese, né a tanti altri maestri della lingua, incluso Migliorini.
Infatti il pronome “gli” è usato spesso anche come “forma atona del dativo plurale maschile e femminile, col sign. di «a loro»: *Chi si cura di costoro a Milano? Chi gli darebbe retta?* (Manzoni); *le belle ragazze di qui non sono degne di portargli le scarpe, a quelle di Napoli* (Verga)” ([Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gli2)). Si veda anche la voce “gli” sul GDLI ([prima](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000929.jpg) e [seconda](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000930.jpg) pagina), con esempi dal Villani fino a Brancati e appunto a Pavese.

Infine si può dire anche

> ...a loro non è chiara

e anche questa forma è leggermente marcata nell'attirare l'attenzione su “loro”.

Il problema, in generale, è che l'uso di “gli” è mal visto in certi ambiti (e, comprensibilmente, può capitare di evitarlo per non rischiare di sembrare ignorante o dover fare tutta la manfrina che ho fatto qui) e quel che resta è l'unico pronome personale dativo non atono dell'italiano, che quindi non può non sbilanciare tutta la frase in cui compare.

Answer (score 3):

Sono entrambe corrette anche se userei *chiaro* (il concetto, il fatto, quanto precede) al maschile e non *chiara* (la cosa, la situazione).

#### Nel parlato

- Nel parlato la prima ("*non è loro chiara*") è un po' più formale.
- La seconda ("*non è chiara a loro*") scorre via  più facilmente anche se, come nota DaG, *pone un po' troppo l'accento su “a loro”, quasi a sottintendere che ad altri invece la cosa è chiara*.

  L'effetto di enfasi viene ancora più marcato se metti una breve pausa tra *"chiara"* e *"a loro"* nel parlare, o anche se aumenti l'emissione di fiato (il volume) dicendo *"a loro"*
  Lo puoi evitare alleggerendo la pressione (volume) quando pronunci *"a loro"*, o diminuendo leggermente la pausa che fai tra *"a loro"* e quanto segue.

#### Nello scritto

Nello scritto non puoi gestire il volume delle parole, ma puoi usare diversi mezzi.

- La prima forma ("*non è loro chiara*") suona di nuovo leggermente più formale, e leggermente più piana: metti meno l'accento su *loro* in contrapposizione ad *altri*. Anche se ci sono sempre artifici stilistici e sintattici per metterlo in evidenza.

  > *...(la cosa) non è loro chiara quando dicono...*
  > *...(la cosa) non è loro chiara.* (E' un fatto che non lo abbiano capito).
  > *...(la cosa) non è loro chiara, mentre nella nostra politica aziendale...*
  > (Sono più i fatti ad essere in contrapposizione che non noi e loro).

  Nella mia esperienza prevale nelle comunicazioni di lavoro.
- La seconda forma ("*non è chiara a loro*") tende ad enfatizzare *"a loro"*.
  Esplicitamente marcata con avversative o con la punteggiatura:

  > *... non è chiara a loro, mentre la nostra politica aziendale...*
  > *... non è chiara, a loro.*

  Più neutra in casi tipo

  > *... non è chiara a loro quando dicono ...*

**Nota sul chiaro al posto di chiara...**
Se passando per strada arriva al tuo orecchio un frammento di frase "NON E' CHIARO" capisci che qualcosa non è stato compreso; se invece senti "NON E' CHIARA" ti viene probabilmente da pensare ad un errore di persona dove si è scambiata Chiara per qualcun'altra.

Comment: La scelta fra chiaro e chiara dipende dal soggetto della frase: “La situazione non gli è chiara”, "il concetto non gli è chiaro" (ovviamente anche con loro/a loro).

Comment: Certamente, @egreg, ma nel mio caso il soggetto era "cosa".